# Find the sum of the first $75$ terms of the arithmetic sequence that starts $5, 8, 11, \ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Find the sum of the first $75$ terms of the arithmetic sequence that starts $5, 8, 11, \ldots$

The answer is $8700$.

I found a formula to be $3x+2$.
So the $1$st term is 
$$3(1)+2=5$$
2nd term 
$$3(2)+2=8$$
3rd term 
$$3(3)+2=11$$
And so on to the 75th term 
$$3(75)+2=227$$
I did not get the right answer? What did I do wrong? Please help?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee OP has already stated what he/she tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_1=5$$
$$u_2=8=5+3$$
$$u_3=11=5+2.3$$
$$u_{75}=5+74.3=227$$

$$S=5+8+11+...+224+227$$
$$S=227+224+...8+5$$
by sum
$$2S=232+232+...232=232.75$$

$$S=116.75=8700$$

Answer (score 6):

The question didn't ask for the *75th term*, it asked for the *sum of the first 75 terms*. So instead of just plugging $75$ into
$$3x+2$$
You instead need to calculate
$$\sum_{x=1}^{75} 3x+2$$

Also, the formula
$$\sum_{x=1}^n x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
may be helpful to you here.